# Are there 'Unitary' clifford alegbras in analogy with Orthogonal and Symplectic (Weyl) Algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras, unitary-matrices

Given a symmetric non-degenerate bi-linear form $G$ on a vector space $V$, I can define the Clifford algebra from the tensor algebra $T(V)$ via:

$$
Cl(V,G) = T(V) / I_G
$$
where $I_G$ is the two sided ideal generated by all elements of the form
$$
I_G = v\otimes v - G(v,v).
$$

Analogously if I have a symplectic form $\omega$ I may build a Weyl algebra by quotienting out the ideal generated by:
$$
I_\omega = v\otimes w - w\otimes v - \omega(v,w).
$$

My question whether there is an analagous algebra which can be made from some hermitian form $h$, perhaps by quotienting out by the ideal generated by
$$
I_h = v^*\otimes v - h(v,v)?
$$
With $h$ is conjugate linear in its first argument.

Does something like this exist and is well studied, perhaps in the Kähler theory? Or is it somehow boring, so not worth studying?

Comment: For clarification, what do you mean by $v\to v^*$? Does your complex vector space have an "underlying real form", so that this is "conjugation"?

Comment: Yes sorry I'm assuming the vector space for the case of the hermitian form, is over the field of complex numbers, and conjugation take its usual form

Comment: @Craig - A general abstract vector space over $\mathbb C$ does not have a conjugation operation. That requires extra structure.

Comment: Apologies, I'm a physicist so it's not always clear to me which things "come for free" as it were. Is it enough to specify a basis, demand conjugation act as the identity on the basis elements, and extend that operation anti-linearly over the field elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
$Note that a conjugation $v \mapsto v^*$ is extra structure and is not inherent to having a Hermitian form.

Here is an answer that shows your proposed algebra is quite boring; I don't know if there's any way to salvage this idea and make an interesting algebra from $h$. The same reasoning ought to hold for the algebra generated by $v\otimes v - h(v,v)$ as well.

Assume $h$ is conjugate-linear in the first argument.
Let its "Hermitian algebra" be denoted by $A$, identify $\C$ and $V$ as subsets of $A$ canonically, and denote the product of $A$ by juxstaposition. For any $v, w \in V$ it follows from the polarization identity
$$
  4h(v,w) = h(v + w) - h(v - w) - ih(v + iw) + ih(v - iw)
$$
with $h(x) = h(x,x) = x^*x$ that
$$
  h(v^*,w) = vw.
$$
Since by definition $A$ is generated by sums of products of vectors it follows that $A = \C\oplus V$ as vector spaces, and in fact this is a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-grading on $A$.

Comment: This is so interesting. Do you have any intuition as to why going to the hermitian case would be so boring, when the bi-linear case is so rich? I can see how it falls out of the polarization identity, but the result isn't totally 'clicking' for me.

Comment: @Craig I think that because $h$ is not (anti-)*symmetric* that it gets "coupled too closely" to the algebra product. In the Clifford case with a symmetric bilinear form $B$ we only get $2B(v,w) = vw + wv$ specifically because $B$ is symmetric so the RHS has to be symmetric as well.

Comment: Thinking about your comment helped. It is as if there is 'too much structure' to satisfy. If one were to "guess" a form of the product to be something like (with bar for conjugation) $2h(v,w) = 2\overline{h}(w,v) = \overline{v}w+\overline{w}v$, this certainly satisfies hermiticity in an analogous way to symmetry in the Clifford case, however it also, via its built in symmetry, equals $h(w,v)$. Hence the analogous guess would imply the hermitian form must be real, which is certainly wrong.