Clifford algebra for hermitian forms
Let $k$ be a CM field with conjugation denoted by $\bar{\cdot}$ and consider an hermitian form $q$ over a $k$ vector space $V$.
I want to construct an analogue of what could be the Clifford algebra attached to $q$.
Recall that (a standard) definition of the Clifford algebra for a quadratic form $f$ over a space $E$ is
to quotient the tensor algebra $T(E)$ by the ideal spanned by the elements of the form $x\otimes x -f(x)1$ for $x$ ranging in $E$.
From this explicit construction, I was thinking of doing the same but with taking into account the conjugation as follows: we quotient the tensor algebra $T(V)$ by the ideal spanned by the $x\otimes \bar{x} -q(x)1$. Remark that in this case, as $q(x)$ is totally real we will get $x\bar x = \bar x x$ in the algebra, which is satisfactory.
Is this hermitian version has been studied systematically somewhere? If so, do we have the same nice classification theorems as for regular Clifford algebras?
I looked online with the terms hermitian Clifford algebra and related terms, but I could not find something very relevant.
Thank you for your help

Relevant, but not sure if it works out the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653580/are-there-unitary-clifford-alegbras-in-analogy-with-orthogonal-and-symplectic/4653718#4653718

What do you mean by "hermitian form" $q(x)$ of one variable? If you mean $q(x) = q(x,x)$ where $q(x,y)$ is hermitian, and these CM fields allow for a polarization identity like in the complex case, then my link answers your question in full: your algebra is very boring in that it is always isomorphic to $k\oplus V$.

Thanks for the answer Nicholas, I meant indeed a form $h(x,y)$ and put $q(x) = h(x,x)$.
As long as you have an element playing the role of the imaginary root your argument works verbatim I suppose, I'll see what happen in the general case.
